# How to passing different data on UICollection every time user push the button?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6, uicollectionview

Can you show me how to passing different data on UICollection every time user push the button, each button is for one data and I have three button. I need to know how to passing data by using button as trigger to change the data. This is my code so far:

```
@IBAction func openNewFilter(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
}
func numberOfSections() -> Int {
    return 2
}

//For the collectionView, number of filters in the section
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return self.filters.count
    } else if section == 1 {
        println("great")
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FILTER_CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FilterThumbnailCell
    var filterThumbnail = self.filterThumbnails[indexPath.row]
    cell.filterTitle.text = filterThumbnail.filterName
    //Lazy Loading

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // set up the standard cell, using the data from the army
        if filterThumbnail.filteredThumbnail != nil {
            cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnail.filteredThumbnail
        } else {
            cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnail.originalThumbnail
            //filterThumbnail is a class instance
            filterThumbnail.generateThumbnail({ (image) -> Void in
                if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? FilterThumbnailCell {
                    cell.imageView.image = image
                }
            })
        }
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        //set up the "+" cell
        println("booya")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Look above, I just edited my question @jycr753

Comment: Can you please add the definition of `filterArray`. Also, have you connected your buttons from your storyboard (assuming you're using one) using IBOutlets? Copy that code too

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your `filterArray` with different content in each action and use it in the `CollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

You already have your array to load data into Collection view i.e. self.filters. What you need to do is on press of each button re-initiate your array with new values and then call

```
        [<Your collectionView> reloadData];
```

By the way is there any use of Collection View section's as i can see in above code?